# What is the difference between > and >> (especially as it relates to use with the cat program)?

Tags: text-processing, io, cat, file-management

Suppose that I have a file called `temp.txt`.  Using the `cat` program, I would like to add the contents of this file to the end of `myfile.txt` -- creating `myfile.txt` if it does not exist and appending to it if it does.

I am considering these possibilities:

```
cat temp.txt > myfile.txt
```

*or*

```
cat temp.txt >> myfile.txt
```

Both commands appear to work as I want.  So, my question is, what is the difference between `>` and `>>`?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`>` writes to a file, overwriting any existing contents. `>>` appends to a file.

From `man bash`:

> ### Redirecting Output
>
> Redirection of output causes the file whose name results from the
>   expansion of word to be opened for writing on file descriptor n, or
>   the standard output (file descriptor 1) if n is not specified. If the
>   file does not exist it is created; if it does exist it is truncated to
>   zero size.
>
> The general format for redirecting output is:
>
> ```
> [n]>word
> ```
>
> If the redirection operator is >, and the noclobber option to the set builtin has been enabled, the redirection will fail
>   if the file whose name results from the expansion of word exists and
>   is a regular file. If the redirection operator is >|, or the
>   redirection operator is > and the noclobber option to the set builtin
>   command is not enabled, the redirection is attempted even if the file
>   named by word exists.
>
> ### Appending Redirected Output
>
> Redirection of output in this fashion causes the file whose name
>   results from the expansion of word to be opened for appending on file
>   descriptor n, or the standard output (file descriptor 1) if n is not
>   specified. If the file does not exist it is created.
>
> The general format for appending output is:
>
> ```
> [n]>>word
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In case of `>`
eg. `cat abc.txt > pqr.txt`
The contents of `pqr.txt` will be replaced with that of `abc.txt`

In case of `>>`
eg. `cat abc.txt >> pqr.txt`
The contents of `abc.txt` will be appended with that `pqr.txt` at the end.