# what is >> symbol and >& in unix/Linux?

Tags: shell-script

I have a CRONTAB entry as below. Can someone tell me what the below statement is exactly doing?

```
1 0 * * * /vol01/sites/provisioning/MNMS/45627/45627.sh1 >> /vol01/sites/provisioning/MNMS/45627/output/cron.log 2>&1
```

Comment: See [What is the difference between > and >> (especially as it relates to use with the cat program)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46974/what-is-the-difference-between-and-especially-as-it-relates-to-use-with-th), [What does “3>&1 1>&2 2>&3” do in a script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42728/what-does-31-12-23-do-in-a-script) and of course, your shell's manual. (There are some further explanations in [Is this a typo in Bash manual's redirection section?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84279/is-this-a-typo-in-bash-manuals-redirection-section) too.)

Comment: @mana ....thanks a lot very useful articles..

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`>` redirects output to a file, overwriting the file.

`>>` redirects output to a file appending the redirected output at the end.

Standard output is represented in bash with number `1` and standard error is represented with number `2`. They are separate, so the user can redirect them to different files.

`2>&1` redirects the standard error to the standard output so they appear together and can be jointly redirected to a file. (Writing just `2>1` would redirect the standard error to a file called "1", not to standard output.)

In your case, you have a job whose output (both standard and error) is appended at the end of a log file (`cron.log`) for later use.

For additional info, check the bash manual (section "Redirection"), [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46974/what-is-the-difference-between-and-especially-as-it-relates-to-use-with-th?lq=1), and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42728/what-does-31-12-23-do-in-a-script?lq=1).

Comment: nice, but what IS this actually? Is it a pipe? An alias?

Answer (score 9):

You should google with keyword **bash redirection** for some detailed information. Here is a nice [article](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/) for reference.

For your question, the crontab will run `45627.sh1` scripts at `00:01` everyday and append its error and output to the `cron.log` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helps. Now I understood Google can't give everything. Experts advice always best :)