# input output redirection in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection

In Ksh for redirecting i/o from a command away from standard output/error I do , [ where command is any command that produces output/error ]

```
command 2>filename
command 2>/dev/null
```

or

```
command &>filename
command &>/dev/null
```

In bash , often I see code like

```
command >&/dev/null
```

what does that additional `&` signify, when the same can be get done by using

```
command> /dev/null
```

I know I am missing something fine, but glad to learn.

EDIT: I knew what 2>&1 is, which the so called duplicate question asks , I was told that 1 indicates a file descriptor and hence we need an & to refer that. I was puzzled to see & before the name of the file. Hence this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>&fname
```

is the same as

```
>fname 2>&1
```

i.e. it redirects **both** stdout and stderr into file `fname`. See `bash(1)` man page, section `REDIRECTION` (especially its part `Redirecting Output`) for detailed explanation.

Comment: awesome. wondering why the documentation says out of &>fname and >&fname , the former is preferred. Thanks a lot of pointing me to the right documentation.

Comment: That documented preference puzzles me too. When csh introduced the `>&` syntax it had to be in that order because the parser wasn't as complicated and `ls &> junk.dat` was semantically equivalent to `ls & ; cat /dev/null > junk.dat`. For the benefit of a reader of a script, I'd still use `>&` to lessen the ambiguity, but I'm pretty old skool.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89388/20291 points to a nice article on redirection.